# check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id=' \r\n

Tags: php, css, mysql

I am new to php and cannot get this! I'm attempting to edit data on an edit page which will be stored through an update page onto mySQL.

```
<?php

include("secure/connect.php");


$newtitle = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, ($_POST['title']));
$newinfo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,($_POST['info']));
$newprice = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,($_POST['price']));
$newmenu_img = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,($_POST['menu_img']));



$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, ($_POST['rowid']));



//setup a SQL query
$query= "UPDATE  cocktails SET title='$newtitle', info='$newinfo',       price='$newprice', menu_img='$newmenu_img', WHERE id='$id'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));


mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I keep getting the error:
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to     your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id='
    \r\nNotice: Undefined variable: iddata in /var/www/vh' at line 1

Comment: Your $id parameter is returned with the `\r\n` aka new line, without actual id? Print out your $id parameter with print_r($id) before you run your SQL query to see that you get it correctly

Comment: remove 'comma' before 'where' clause and try

Answer (score 1):

If your parameters are OK, removing comma(,) in this line

```
UPDATE cocktails SET title='$newtitle', info='$newinfo', price='$newprice', menu_img='$newmenu_img', WHERE id='$id'
```

before `WHERE` will do the job. Note that MariaDB will start code in error message from exactly the part that gives error - in your case it tries to parse `WHERE` part as continuation of list of parameters.

Your code is also vulnerable to SQL code injection, so check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) before sending your code into production server.